# Error using handlebars-template

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars-template like bellow,

```
   <script id="pins-list-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#if ListCount > 0}}
        <ul>
          {{#each ListData}}
            <li>
              <img src="assets/3dimage.png" data-src="{{thumbURL}}"/>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
       </ul>
     {{else}}
        Empty Result
     {{/if}}
  </script>
```

If i try to render this, I am getting this error ,

> Error: Parse error on line 3: {{#if ListCount > 0}}  {
>   ----------------^ Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'EQUALS',
>   'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'

Answer (score 1):

Try using main array.length instead of > 0

```
{{#if ListData.length}}
   <ul>
     {{#each ListData}}
         <li>
           <img src="assets/3dimage.png" data-src="{{thumbURL}}"/>
        </li>
     {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{else}}
    Empty Result
{{/if}}
```

In order to use > 0 you would need to write a helper (e.g is-greater)

Nb! Javascript preffers camelCase naming conventions, only classes are capitalized.

Comment: Javascript uses WatheverCase naming conventions, but yes it's preferred to use camelCase for vars and PascalCase for classes, but you can do what you want in JS

Answer (score 0):

Try evaluating the function in JavaScript and then passing the result in the context:

```
context.ListHasData = (context.ListCount > 0);

YourHandleBarsTemplate(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

I search on that and found a solution.
Take a look to that : http://jsfiddle.net/a9wjbsch/520/
You need to use an handlebars helper :)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function (lvalue, rvalue, options) {

if (arguments.length < 3)
    throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' needs 2 parameters");

var operator = options.hash.operator || "==";

var operators = {
    '==': function (l, r) { return l == r; },
    '===': function (l, r) { return l === r; },
    '!=': function (l, r) { return l != r; },
    '<': function (l, r) { return l < r; },
    '>': function (l, r) { return l > r; },
    '<=': function (l, r) { return l <= r; },
    '>=': function (l, r) { return l >= r; },
    'typeof': function (l, r) { return typeof l == r; }
}

if (!operators[operator])
    throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' doesn't know the operator " + operator);

var result = operators[operator](lvalue, rvalue);

if (result) {
    return options.fn(this);
} else {
    return options.inverse(this);
}
```